# Creating area charts with multiple transparent entries (MIT/GNU)

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, charts

Are you aware of any good plugin/script (could be jquery or html5's canvas) under MIT/GNU license that would allow me to construct and modify an area chart with transparency?

Something in the lines of:

[image]

Although I don't need the curves, it can just steps in 90 degrees, like this but overlapping:

[image]

The google charts api has some interesting applications, but I'd rather use something with an open source license. There are some nice jQuery and canvas chart generators, but they either don't cover area charts OR allow multiple entries in the same chart. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of these,

- **[flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/)**
- **[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)**  *[example that shows different types](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html)*

and the big daddy that you can do pretty much anything with

- **[d3](http://d3js.org/)**

Comment: Thanks Loktar. I went with Flot and the stacked example: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/stacking.html